# How to push a constant value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to push a value in an array. The array is on the scope. It seems like a pretty simple operation. Am I missing something?

```
(function () {
    angular.module('myApp', [])
       .constant('dataTypes', [{ 'key': 'Number', 'Value': 1 }, { 'key': 'Text', 'Value': 2 }, { 'key': 'DateTime', 'Value': 3 }])
       .constant('blankColumn', { 'name': 'Column', 'type': 2, 'description': '' })
       .controller('columnsController', ['$scope', 'dataTypes', 'blankColumn', columnsController])


    function columnsController($scope, dataTypes, blankColumn) {
        $scope.model = {};

        $scope.model.addColumn = function () {
            if (!$scope.model.columns) {
                $scope.model.columns = [];
            }

            $scope.model.columns.push(blankColumn);  //Error here. The first index is rendered but others are not
        };
    }
})();
```

When I push a blankColumn the columns property is pupulated but only the first index is rendered. The columns propoerty is being displayed in a ng-repeater.

Comment: when same object(value) is pushed in array angular treat it as same value the digest of angular render it only one time. just add any new filed. it will definitively work. in your case it is constant so it can't be modified at run time

Comment: @BharatBhushan I don't know what you mean. 'Just add any new filled'. What does that mean? If you mean field how would I do that?

Comment: try to add id with with current time while pushing into column

Comment: wait i am making plunker for you

Comment: Done check the plunker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use track by with `$index` in your case to repeat duplicate entry in array.

[here is plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/L0aagwGo3pOoZJCUVp1A?p=preview)